# How do I find out the font of the title of Toplevel?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am computing the width of a `Toplevel` window based on the title and the text inside. For the text inside, there is no problem, since I am the one who set the `font` property of the text and so I can use the `measure` method of the font. In contrast, there does not seem to be a way to set the font of the title. But how can I at least get the font that is being used?

Comment: What do it this way? You can just measure top level with `widget.winfo_height() and widget.winfo_width()`

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I am measuring the text in order to set the size of `Toplevel` accordingly, i.e. to fit the text that is going to be displayed in it.

Comment: Ah ok. It is a little different to worry about the window frame text but would be good to know if its possible. I will do some research.

Comment: You may not be able to get info about the title bar however you can disable the title bar with `overrideredirect()` and then make your own title bar with a label or a frame. This should allow you to set any font you wish and be able to calc your width.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Are you really saying that there is no easy way to make sure that `Toplevel` is wide enough to contain its title?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter does not provide a way to get at information about the decorations added by the window manager or os. You will have to find some platform-specific method of getting that information.

Comment: Isn't there an easy way to make sure that `Toplevel` is wide enough to contain its title?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: No, there is not.

Comment: This is hard to believe. I mean, that's just shameful. Isn't that a very basic requirement? Note that I posted this as a question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44541189/2725810